# How to handle the states when disabling my component in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

What I want is to make the `TextPanel` disabled if `payStub` has a value, and not be disabled if `payStub` does not have a value,

In my React code, I have the following:

```js
const [payStub, setPayStub] = useState(() => {
  if (isNewPayStub) {
    return get(user, 'stub', '');
  }
  return stubEdit.value?.name || '';
}); 

const stubIsValid = Boolean(trim(payStub));
```

And in the React side I have the following:

```
return (
  <Panel
    onClose={onClose}
    onSave={handleSave}
    addNewText={isNewPayStub ? 'Add New PayStub' : ''}
  >    
    ....
        
    <TextPanel
      handleChange={setPayStub}
      isValid={stubIsValid}
      isRequired
      label="Stub"
      placeholder="Enter STUB"
      value={payStub}
    />
```

The `TextPanel` receives a property of `disabled`, and when I add a property as `disabled: {stubIsValid}`, when the user enters the first character, the condition will be met and it makes the `TextPanel` disabled which is not what I want (user should be able to fill enter the payStub).

How do I fix this situation?

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Where is `TextField`?

Comment: @ggorlen Apologies this was a typo. I meant TextPanel which is included here. 
Corrected

Comment: Thanks but I'm still seeing two little chunks of code taken out of context. It's very difficult to write an answer based on that. Please share a full, runnable component.

Comment: _when the user enters the first character, the condition will be met_ - it's most likely because you are firing `setPayStub` on `onChange` inside `TextPanel`, you have to change it either to `onBlur` or on a button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
#create new variable to set the disabled value;
const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(payStub ? true : false);


#Then create a onblur function
const handleBlur = (e) => {
        let val = e.target.value;

            if(val){
                setIsDisabled(true)
            }else{
                setIsDisabled(false)
            }          
    };
```

#Then on your TextPanel you can add this.
This is to handle the disabled element whether your payStub variable has value or none.

```
<TextPanel
    handleChange={setPayStub}
    isValid={stubIsValid}
    isRequired
    label="Stub"
    placeholder="Enter STUB"
    value={payStub}
    onBlur={handleBlur}
    disabled = {isDisabled}
/>
```

Hope it will help.